# How to shrink root / partition and add a new one

Tags: raspbian, partition

I have a 4 GB SD card with only two partitions

> `/boot` ~50 Mb
>   `/` (root) ~3900 Mb ext4

and I need to shrink the root partition to about 3 GB to use the following schema

> `/boot` ~50 Mb
>   `/` (root) ~3000 Mb ext4
>   `/var` ~900 Mb ext4

Then I want to mount `/` read only and `/var/` read-write.

I'm no expert in using `parted` or modifying `/etc/fstab` I'm looking for some directions on how to resize the partitions and add the correct entries. I'm running Raspbian wheezy, already backupped everything with `dd` on my macbook laptop.
Thank you.

**edit**: I forgot I have no GUI running on the Pi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's very unlikely you'll be able to resize the partition using RasPi without any other linux-running computer. basically you have to issue:

```
resize2fs /dev/sdX1 900M
```

however, your volume should not be mounted at that moment, and there are plenty of other details you may check in [this tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_resizing_ext3_partitions)

also, i'd recommend to get another SD card and create the necessary partitions there, with the data migration afterwards, because it's very easy to damage the original during the process.